# unable to use <bean:write> inside <html:select>

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, struts

```
</tr>
<tr style="height:30px">
<td width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="20%" align="right"><b><bean:message key="abc.title" /><font
color="red">*</font> </b>&nbsp;</td>`enter code here`
<td width="30%" align="left"><input
id="title<bean:write name="listInstance"
       property="listInstanceId"/>"
name="textfield" type="text" class="inp_Textbox"
maxlength="100" size="55"/></td>


<td width="20%" align="right"><b><bean:message key="abc.userParties" /> </b>&nbsp;</td>
<td width="30%" align="left">
<html:select
property="arrUserPartiesid"  styleId="arrUserPartiesid<bean:write name="listInstance"
       property="listInstanceId"/>" style="width:100px" name="UserForm"
styleClass="inp_Textbox" multiple="true" >
<html:optionsCollection name="USER PARTIES" />
</html:select>
</td>
```

how can i append something to styleID like i appended it with  to id="title". I'am getting an error "equal symbol not identified" if i do it like this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.. but I think you could just use js innerHTML, for example

var childDiv = document.createElement("div");
childDiv.innerHTML = '<span id="title">any HTML you want</span>';
var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parent_div_id");  
parentDiv .appendChild(childDiv );

Comment: You cannot nest custom tags like that. innerHTML is generally a bad idea. Depending on what version of things you're using you can probably just use EL.